# convert dateYYYY-MM-DD to yyyymmdd

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe in R with dates being one of the column

```
head(t)  
#    date       x  
#2013-04-05   32851  
#2013-04-06   42523
#...
```

I need to parse the date and get `20130405`, `20130506` as another column in the same data frame.
How do I do this ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `gsub`...

```
df$new <- gsub( "-" , "" , df$date )
        date     x      new
1 2013-04-05 32851 20130405
2 2013-04-06 42523 20130406
```